# python GET and POST with json and variables

Tags: python, json

get parse post

I can't seem to get this to work. This is what I think is happening: (But obviously I am doing something wrong.)

1. User gives me in the form of nid.
2. Take nid and construct url to GET json dump.
3. Take value of title and body from json dump and store in variables title and body.
4. Construct another url with the various variables and POST to site 2.

Attempt:

```
import requests
import json

#Token used to post
auth_token = "X"

#Take and parse payload for title and body at site 1.
def payload(nid):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    with urlopen("www.site1.com/" + nid + ".json") as rr:
        result = json.loads(rr.read().decode(rr.headers.get_content_charset("utf-8")))
    title = (result["title"])
    body = (result["body"]["und"])

#Take title, body, auth_token and then also nid from user input, and POSTing  to site 2 
def add(nid):
    url = "www.site2.com/stuff.json"
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    payload = {
        "auth_token": auth_token,
        "document":
            {
                "external_id": nid,
                "fields": [
                    {"name": "title", "value": title, "type": "string"},
                    {"name": "path", "value": "www.site1.com/node/"+nid,"type": "enum"},
                    {"name": "nid", "value": nid, "type": "integer"},
                    {"name": "body", "value": body, "type": "text"},
                ]}
    }

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print("{} was added".format(nid))

while True:

#Trigger User Input
    new_item = input("> ")

#Add nid
    if new_item == "A":
        nid = input("Give me an NID please: ")
        payload(nid)
        add(nid)
```

Comment: What is the problem or error ?

Comment: No error. The POST does not actually make it to the other website. Or at least no data is posted. If I add static values instead of title and body in the add fuction, it does work. I can also print the parsed data in the payload function. But of them both do not work? Does it have data I am trying to post? Encoding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not passed title ,body in the `def add(nid)` function parameters/arguments.
So to correct this, modify `def payload(nid)` to return body/title & pass this arguments as to `add(nid,title,body)` function.

Hope this helps!

```
import requests
import json

#Token used to post
auth_token = "X"

#Take and parse payload for title and body at site 1.
def payload(nid):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    with urlopen("www.site1.com/" + nid + ".json") as rr:
        result = json.loads(rr.read().decode(rr.headers.get_content_charset("utf-8")))
    title = (result["title"])
    body = (result["body"]["und"])
    return (title,body)
#Take title, body, auth_token and then also nid from user input, and POSTing  to site 2 
def add(nid,title,body):
    url = "www.site2.com/stuff.json"
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    payload = {
        "auth_token": auth_token,
        "document":
            {
                "external_id": nid,
                "fields": [
                    {"name": "title", "value": title, "type": "string"},
                    {"name": "path", "value": "www.site1.com/node/"+nid,"type": "enum"},
                    {"name": "nid", "value": nid, "type": "integer"},
                    {"name": "body", "value": body, "type": "text"},
                ]}
    }

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print("{} was added".format(nid))

while True:

#Trigger User Input
    new_item = input("> ")

#Add nid
    if new_item == "A":
        nid = input("Give me an NID please: ")
        title,body = payload(nid)
        add(nid,title,body)
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do so?

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure this is working. My post is just not hitting the other website for some reason. Either way, thanks for your help! Day 3.5 of Python :)

Comment: well you mentioned in comment that it was working with static title and body but not using variables . So, i suggested this. You can try debugging what are title and body coming from `payload()` function

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it is working if I use body with static content. Seems like the actual data that i get in the body is causing the post to fail. Doing some side research it looks like beautiful soup may be a good option to add in here for scrapping the html tags and such out of the body before posting.